# ASP.Net Dynamically switch Master Pages

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Never needed to do this before but is it possible to dynamically set/change which master page a page is using?  Have an old asp.net web forms project which I have created a new bootstrap template for but the boss wants to give people the opportunity to switch on the new one instead of forcing it upon them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you to create  a BasePage class than write this method in that class and inherit all of your pages from this class whose master page can be changed dynamically.

```
public class BasePage: System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (conduction1)
            this.Page.MasterPageFile = "~/MasterPage.master";
        else
            this.Page.MasterPageFile = "~/Master.master";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
}
```

And then in your page inherit page from BasePage like this

```
public partial class _Default:BasePage
```

Answer (score 2):

The master page is changed only in `preint` event

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (conduction1)
                this.Page.MasterPageFile = "~/MasterPage.master";
            else
                this.Page.MasterPageFile = "~/Master.master";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

or

```
void page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Page page = sender as Page;
   page.MasterPageFile = "string location of masterpage";
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that simple huh.  Is it easy to apply it globally without having to change each pages PreInit function?

Comment: i think you can do this globally with HTTP handler