# Session checking in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I was assigned to a older project been done in asp webforms. So in every page load I found code like

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserDetails"] != null)
```

For checking if session is active for visiting the page. Is there any single point where I can write this code so that if user is inactive loginPage is presented.

Comment: do you have `MasterPage`?

Comment: @Amit Kumar. For some pages. Or do I have to go for Forms authentication. Am very new

Comment: you might want to check it in your `MasterPages's` load event.Though it's preety simple to check for valid `Session` variable before you try to access data inside it.

Comment: Can you describe or show the pages which you have in project.

Comment: @MairajAhmad As i said its written in every page not having a master page

Comment: So one thing you can do is create a base page class and in this class write an event page_load and in this check session. And inherit all your pages from that base page.

Comment: @MairajAhmad is this the right way Or Do ihave to move to forms authetication

Comment: FormsAuthentication is for authentication purposes it depends on your bussiness logic that what is suitable for you.

Comment: Here is a little example of Base page and its usage.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662575/asp-net-dynamically-switch-master-pages/25662796#25662796

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could achieve your task with a HTTPModule:

Example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227673%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Web;
public class HelloWorldModule : IHttpModule
{
    public HelloWorldModule()
    {
    }

    public String ModuleName
    {
        get { return "HelloWorldModule"; }
    }

    // In the Init function, register for HttpApplication 
    // events by adding your handlers.
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += 
            (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
        application.EndRequest += 
            (new EventHandler(this.Application_EndRequest));
    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, 
         EventArgs e)
    {
    // Create HttpApplication and HttpContext objects to access
    // request and response properties.
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;
        string fileExtension = 
            VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(filePath);
        if (fileExtension.Equals(".aspx"))
        {
            // test here your session
        }
    }

    private void Application_EndRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

You should register this module in your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="HelloWorldModule" type="HelloWorldModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have controller page, how about this way?

Controller page.

```
[SessionExpireFilter]
public void functionname()
{
   //you're function region page?
}
```

New createpage.

```
public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserDetails"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Login");
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```